# how to convert output of MY SQL Query to Access Database

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-access, odbc

In my project i need to extract output of MySQL query into MS Access database. that mean what ever is the output of MySQL query should go to ms access databse in table say T1. it has no more tables just one table.  I have converted SqlQuery into datatable. How can i write datatable into MSAccess table T1 using c# :

```
myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString; 
OdbcCommand cmd= new OdbcCommand(); 
cmd.CommandType= CommandType.Text; 
myConnection.Open(); 
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++) { 
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t1 (column1) VALUES ('" +      dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0) + "')"; cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

Comment: @PaulF  
                    myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                    OdbcCommand cmd= new OdbcCommand();
                     cmd.CommandType= CommandType.Text;
                     myConnection.Open();
                           for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                                {  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO t1 (column1)   VALUES ('" + dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0) + "')";
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }

Comment: What errors do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your exception message is saying to you that you don't have a valid Connection, this is just because you are not assigning a valid connection to your `OdbcCommand`, try initializing your `OdbcCommand` in this  way :

```
OdbcCommand cmd= new OdbcCommand(CommandType.Text, myConnection);
```

*And use a Query parameter instead of String query concatenation ...*

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you :

```
using (OdbcConnection myConnection = new OdbcConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        String insSQL = "INSERT INTO t1 (column1) VALUES ('" + dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0) + "')";
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(insSQL, myConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```